# Pass nvarchar(max) from stored procedure to SSIS

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, nvarchar

I have stored procedure which has 4 input parameters and 1 output parameter. I call it from SSIS Execute SQL Task. Now the problem is that, the output parameter is `NVARCHAR` with 110k characters. So this output parameter holds the JSON string because JSON string is easy to modify and manipulate in SQL Server.

The issue is that this output parameter is getting truncated and I am getting only 32767 characters in SSIS. So I get an error that JSON is not properly formatted.

Please suggest a solution or an alternative.

Comment: Sorry I updated my question with the problem. I just want to know how to pass nvarchar value of 110k characters from stored procedure to SSIS variable.

Comment: I think this is a limitation in SSIS.  Why not save the output to a temp table and read it in the SSIS next step?

Comment: i will try it out and update whatever i find. Thank you :)